# Is it possible to determine is a boost::basic_lockable_adapter is currently locked?

Tags: c++, boost, locking, mutex

We've been using Boost's `basic_lockable_adapter` and `strict_lock` in our project for thread synchronization. We've determined a situation that could possibly lead to a deadlock, and we want to avoid this situation. If we were able to detect if the `basic_lockable_adapter` was locked or not, we could assert on that and catch it during development.

Here is an example of what I'm looking for (this code is compilable, except for the fact that one function doesn't exist):

```
#include <boost/thread/lockable_adapter.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/strict_lock.hpp>
#include <mutex>

class Controller : public boost::basic_lockable_adapter<std::recursive_mutex>
{
public:
    static Controller& instance() { static Controller instance; return instance; }
};

void check_for_lock()
{
    // is_locked() isn't real ... but I'd like that functionality somehow
    if (Controller::instance().is_locked())
        std::cout << "It's locked." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Not locked." << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    check_for_lock();
    boost::strict_lock<Controller> lock(Controller::instance());
    check_for_lock();

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to implement the equivalent of `.is_locked()`?

**Edit - Clarification**

I forgot to mention an important point. We use the "external locking" paradigm as explained in the Boost documentation. With that, a function that absolutely needs to hold the lock simply expects a reference as a parameter - therefore, if you get the parameter, you know you have the lock.

In my case, it's the opposite. I want to know whether *the current thread currently has a lock*, from a function that does not expect the `strict_lock` as a parameter, so I can assert or throw.

So: The function knows what the `lockable_adapter` is, but needs to know if the currently executing thread has that lock or not (it doesn't care about other threads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe your goal is 100% feasible using an unadorned `std::recursive_mutex`. Although you could attempt test locks by calling `try_lock()` on the current thread and a separate thread, analyzing those results won't give you a definitive answer. One reason is that the standard allows `try_lock()` to fail spuriously, even when the mutex is available. Another reason is that there is an implementation-defined limit on recursion, after which `try_lock()` will fail.

Can you substitute your own mutex type? If so, then you can wrap `std::recursive_mutex` with your own class that records the thread holding the lock. For example:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/thread/lockable_adapter.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/strict_lock.hpp>

class MyMutex {
   std::recursive_mutex m_;

   std::mutex auxMutex_;
   std::thread::id id_;
   unsigned int count_;
public:
   MyMutex() : count_(0) {}

   void lock() {
      m_.lock();
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(auxMutex_);
      if (!count_++)
         id_ = std::this_thread::get_id();
   }

   void unlock() {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(auxMutex_);
      --count_;
      m_.unlock();
   }

   bool try_lock() {
      if (m_.try_lock()) {
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(auxMutex_);
         if (!count_++)
            id_ = std::this_thread::get_id();
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

   std::thread::id id() {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(auxMutex_);
      return count_ ? id_ : std::thread::id();
   }
};

class Controller : public boost::basic_lockable_adapter<MyMutex>
{
   // Allow access to protected lockable() member function.
   friend void check_for_lock();

public:
    static Controller& instance() { static Controller instance; return instance; }
};

void check_for_lock()
{
   auto& lockable = Controller::instance().lockable();
   if (lockable.id() == std::this_thread::get_id())
      std::cout << "locked in current thread" << std::endl;
   else
      std::cout << "not locked in current thread" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    check_for_lock();
    boost::strict_lock<Controller> lock(Controller::instance());
    check_for_lock();

    return 0;
}
```

In the wrapper class `MyMutex`, `count_` tracks the recursion level and `id_` records the last thread to lock. Otherwise the lock manipulation calls are forwarded to the actual `std::recursive_mutex`.

Getting a reference to the mutex from the adapter does require access to the protected `lockable()` member function. I've therefore made `check_for_lock()` a friend function, or it could be made a member function. Its implementation becomes a simple matter of comparing thread ids.

Comment: I was thinking some sort of wrapper would be required, but I wasn't sure if it should be around the `lockable_adapter`, `strict_lock`, or the `mutex`. I'll implement something like this tomorrow, and if it does the job the bounty is your's. :)

Answer (score 2):

Strict locks /always/ own the lock (that's what makes them *strict*).

`unique_lock` has `owns_lock()`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/owns_lock. It also has implicit conversion to `bool` that does exactly the same!

You can *statically* determine whether a generic type is strict locking. There's a largish discussion of how to piece it together for generic lock types in the boost documentation: **[Allowing other strict locks](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.tutorial.external_locking_____strict_lock__and__externally_locked__classes.allowing_other_strict_locks)**

Comment: I'm not sure this completely answered things - but dinner is served :| Revisiting later

Comment: You're absolutely correct, however I forgot to add an important detail to my question - it's been updated now. I need to know whether the current thread has a lock at the moment, from a function that doesn't take `strict_lock` as a parameter.